# Android ComponentInfo and NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

in application sometimes i'm get this error and after trace i cant find whats cause of this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ir.tsms/ir.tsms.ServiceDialog}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ir.tsms.ServiceDialog.updateAndIntertDialog(ServiceDialog.java:233)
    at ir.tsms.ServiceDialog.onCreate(ServiceDialog.java:105)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
    ... 11 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ir.tsms.ServiceDialog.updateAndIntertDialog(ServiceDialog.java:233)
    at ir.tsms.ServiceDialog.onCreate(ServiceDialog.java:105)
```

i get `NullPointerException` error and i can not resolve that.

my code:

```
public class ServiceDialog extends Activity {
    private Context ctx;
    private String count;
    private Boolean ps;
    private Boolean sn;
    private String mLastIDForDelete;
    private String mLastID;
    private String mSmsNumber;
    private String mMobileNumber;
    private String mContactName;
    private String mSmsBody;
    private String mSenderName;
    private String mDate;
    private MediaPlayer sms_music;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
    private TextView count_sms;
    private ContentResolver contentResolver;
    private boolean getCurrentActivity;
    private LinearLayout open_app;
    private TextView content;
    private TextView title;
    private TextView tv_date_time;
    private TextView tv_name_family;
    private TextView te_sms_text;
    private TextView tv_phone_number;
    private LinearLayout main_window;
    private Integer  notify = 0;
    private Integer  unread_messages;
    private Integer  unread_count    = 0;

    private static final String TAG = "BroadcastTest";
    private Intent intent;
    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        requestWindowFeature ( Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE );
        getWindow ().setFlags ( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );
        setContentView ( R.layout.service_view_dialog );

        ctx = getBaseContext ();
        G.redirect = false;
        /* Set current Activity runnable with this activity class */
        G.activity = this;
        intent = new Intent(this, ToobaPayamakService.class);
        unread_messages = 0;

        title                 = (TextView) findViewById ( R.id.tv_title );
        content               = (TextView) findViewById ( R.id.content );
        count_sms             = (TextView) findViewById ( R.id.tv_count_new_sms );
        tv_date_time          = (TextView) findViewById ( R.id.tv_date_time );
        tv_name_family        = (TextView) findViewById ( R.id.tv_name_family );
        tv_phone_number       = (TextView) findViewById ( R.id.tv_phone_number );
        te_sms_text           = (EditText) findViewById ( R.id.te_sms_text );
        title.setText          ( ctx.getResources ().getString ( R.string.count_new_sms_received ) );
        main_window           = (LinearLayout) findViewById ( R.id.main_window );


        int count  = 0;
        int unread= 0;
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent ().getExtras ();
            if (extras == null) {
                count = 0;
            } else {
                G.config_username = extras.getString ( "username" );
                G.config_password = extras.getString ( "password" );
                unread            = extras.getInt    ( "unread"   );
                notify            = extras.getInt    ( "notify"   );
                G.db              = new DatabaseHandler ( G.context );
            }
        }
        contentResolver = ctx.getContentResolver ();
        updateAndIntertDialog( unread, contentResolver);
        notification();
        Button   send_sms              = (Button)   findViewById ( R.id.send_sms );

        open_app                       = (LinearLayout) findViewById ( R.id.open_app );
        LinearLayout delete            = (LinearLayout) findViewById ( R.id.delete );
        LinearLayout forward           = (LinearLayout) findViewById ( R.id.forward );

        /* get realtime configuration saved settings */
        open_app.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {
                Intent tsms_dashboard = new Intent ( v.getContext (), ActivityMain.class );
                startActivity ( tsms_dashboard );
                finish ();
            }
        } );

        delete.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {
                /*G.db.deleteRecordFromReceiveds( mLastIDForDelete );
                if( getCurrentActivity ){
                    G.fillItems ( G.contentResolver );
                    G.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }*/
            }
        });

        forward.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {
                G.forward_text_from_service = mSmsBody;
                G.config_smsNumber = tv_phone_number.getText ().toString ();
                Intent tsms_dashboard = new Intent(v.getContext(), ActivityContactList.class);
                startActivity(tsms_dashboard);
                finish();
            }
        });
        /* Set Screen Turn ON */
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
        params.screenBrightness = 1.0f;
        getWindow().setAttributes(params);

        PowerManager powermanager =  ((PowerManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE));
        wakeLock=powermanager.newWakeLock(
                PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK |
                        PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TsmsScreenOn");
        wakeLock.acquire();

        startService(intent);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter (ToobaPayamakService.BROADCAST_ACTION));
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            updateUI(intent);
        }
    };

    private void updateUI(Intent intent) {
        String counter = intent.getStringExtra ( "counter" );
        Log.e ("counter in update UI", counter);
        updateAndIntertDialog( Integer.valueOf ( counter ), contentResolver);
        //count_sms.setText ( counter );
        //notification();
    }


    public void updateAndIntertDialog( Integer received_count , ContentResolver cr){
        unread_messages += received_count;
        getCurrentActivity = Configuration.getInstance ()
                .getBoolean ( getApplication (),
                        Configuration.SharedPrefsTypes.ACTIVITY_IS_RUNNING );
        int count        = received_count - 1;
        int cursor_count = 0;
        String mUserID   = "";
        String mLastID   = "";
        String mSmsBody  = "";
        String mSenderName  = "";
        String mContactName = "";
        String mSmsNumber   = "";
        String mDate        = "";
        Cursor c      = G.db.getReceivedFromDatabaseByCount( G.config_username , received_count);
        c.moveToLast ();
        if ( c != null && c.getCount() != 0 ) {
            cursor_count = c.getCount ();
            Log.e("cursor count is: ", c.getCount ()+"");
            for( int i = cursor_count; i > 0; i--){
                mUserID = G.config_username;
                mLastID = c.getString ( c.getColumnIndex ( "lastId" ) );
                mSmsBody = c.getString ( c.getColumnIndex ( "smsBody" ) );
                mSenderName = c.getString ( c.getColumnIndex ( "senderName" ) );
                //Log.e("Fill Items "," mSenderName:" + mSenderName + " ContentResolver: "+cr);
                mContactName = G.getContentNameFromContactList ( mSenderName, cr );
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty ( mContactName ))
                    /* if contact name not exist in contact show resolve by service */
                    mContactName = mSenderName;
                mSmsNumber = c.getString ( c.getColumnIndex ( "smsNumber" ) );
                mDate = c.getString ( c.getColumnIndex ( "receiveDate" ) );
                Bitmap mPhoto = G.getContactPhoto ( mSenderName, cr );
                int mRead = Integer.parseInt ( c.getString ( c.getColumnIndex ( "read_state" ) ) );
                ReceivedItemStructure itm = new ReceivedItemStructure ();
                itm.setmLastID       ( mLastID );
                itm.setmUserID       ( mUserID );
                itm.setmSmsBody      ( mSmsBody );
                itm.setmSmsNumber    ( mSmsNumber );
                itm.setmSenderName   ( mSenderName );
                itm.setmContactName  ( mContactName );
                itm.setmDate         ( mDate );
                itm.setmRead         ( mRead );
                itm.setmPhoto        ( mPhoto );
                Log.e ( "---------- lastID: ", mLastID );
                G.items.add ( 0, itm );
                c.moveToPrevious();
            }
        }
        c.close();
        mLastIDForDelete = mLastID;
        tv_name_family.setText ( mContactName );
        tv_phone_number.setText ( mSmsNumber );
        tv_date_time.setText   ( mDate.substring(11, 16) );
        mMobileNumber = G.getContactMobile ( mContactName );
        content.setText        ( mSmsBody );
        count_sms.setText ( unread_messages+"" );
        if( getCurrentActivity ){
            G.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();
        }

        //main_window.setVisibility ( View.VISIBLE );
        try {
            Thread.sleep ( 2000 );
            notification ();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }

    }
}
```

line 223 is end of `updateAndIntertDialog` function and `ServiceDialog.java:105` is calling `updateAndIntertDialog` function

Comment: If I get a NPE, I print out every Object of that line that could be null... try this way. Just System.out.println("Debug NPE: " + G + "  " + adapter) if line 223 is G.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Your `G.adapter` is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is Contentresolver null ? Try in onCreate method instead

```
 contentResolver = ctx.getContentResolver ();
```

call

```
 contentResolver = this.getContentResolver();
```

or

```
 contentResolver = getContentResolver();
```

Comment: thanks sir. why in logcat i can not see exactly cause of problem? (logcat) is very unclear and i can not trace correctly and trace application to find errors